# Ruby on Rails Tableless Model Associations with Legacy Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm just learning RoR, and am trying to build a Model around my legacy database, which is built more around SPROCs for querying data. I've found the [activerecord-tableless](http://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-tableless) gem and am using that to help build the models.

So far, I'm able to get the base model working OK:

```
class Wine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_no_table

  self.primary_key = "iWine"

  column :iWine, :integer
  column :Wine, :string
  column :Vintage, :integer
  ....etc......

  attr_accessible :iWine, :Wine, :Vintage, .....

  has_many :labelImages

  def self.find_wine(id)
    r = ActiveRecord::Base.execute_procedure "sp_FetchWineVerbose", 'iWine' => id.to_i
    if r.size > 0
      w = Wine.new(r[0])
      return w;
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I'd like to take advantage of ActiveRecord's associations to pull in additional pieces of related data, e.g. label images, other vintages, etc. Here is what I have so far:

```
class LabelImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_no_table

  column :id, :integer
  column :width, :integer
  column :height, :integer
  column :wine_id, :integer

  attr_accessible :id, :width, :height, :wine_id
  after_initialize :fetch_data

  belongs_to :wine

  def fetch_data()
    sql = <<-eos
SELECT iLabel AS id, Width AS width, Height AS height, ....
eos

    r = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql, 'Label Image', [[wine_id,wine_id]])
    if r.size > 0
        self.assign_attributes(r[0])
    end
  end
end
```

So, now, I can call `w = Wine.find_wine(1)` and then `w.labelImages.build`, and I get back a LabelImage object with the right data. But, I also get the following message in the console:

```
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for 1:Fixnum
```

I've tried digging through the source code but cannot figure out where this is coming from. And, I also can't figure out how to override the initialization to return an array of multiple LabelImage objects -- as there may be many for any given wine. Should I override the `build` method (and if so, how?), or is there another way to create the objects and then assign them to the Wine.labelImages attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You may be going about this the hard way, `activerecord-tableless` gem is really for information not stored in SQL databases.

I would suggest looking at something like `https://rubygems.org/gems/rmre` that could help build active_models based on you existing schema.

Comment: Yes, I probably am going about it the hard way :) I haven't found any good tutorials/samples that seem similar to what I want, so I've just been trying to modify the 'standard' way. I'll take a look at `rmre`, thanks for the pointer! However, I don't see an obvious way to plug in my stored procedures (SPROCs) for fetching the data instead of the ActiveRecord generated SQL? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: How complex is the schema? If it's actually wine and wine labels it seems like stored procedures are way overkill. `ActiveRecord` will allow you to do all the queries you need.  If you can use something like Visio to generate an ER diagram?  I could advise further.

Comment: The schema is quite complex; I was just trying to simplify into an easy-to-digest concrete example. We have about 160 different tables (not including views), and a lot of data is dynamic and dependent on the user requesting it -- so even 'simple' queries can involve a lot of JOINs. For us, it's much more efficient to push a lot of that logic to the DB and simply use SPROCs as the interface to query/update data. (Plus, we have an existing ASP/VBScript front-end that needs to continue to exist.)

Comment: `activerecord` does support stored procedures, I have not used them myself though.  Have a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657160/why-are-stored-procedures-still-not-supported-in-rails-3` and `https://gist.github.com/wok/1367987` I would say you are taking on a pretty big task for a first rails project.  I would still look at `rmre` and try to get to the point where you can see a couple of tables and have models with relationships, then you could add stored procedures.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. We're using SQL Server, and I haven't had any issues calling the stored procedures. I have an object model in mind that I want to create around the data, but it's not exactly a 1:1 mapping to tables like ActiveRecord wants. My struggle, being new to Ruby+Rails, is how to properly bridge the gap. I can make the db queries (via execute_procedure and select_all), but I'm unclear whether I should try and wedge those into ActiveRecord derived classes, or just generic ones. I'd love to use the other benefits of ActiveRecord (validations, associations). Any thoughts on that?